# Symfony 4 disable profiler in controller action

Tags: symfony, profiler

I have an action in the controller for mass instert in the database...
So this uses a lot of resources and the profiler is caching everything and server goes down.

How can i disable the profiler (and all the debug services) in one action on the controller?

The controller looks like :

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use App\Sync\Incomming\Syncronize;

/**
* @Route("/sync")
*/
class SyncController extends AbstractController
{
    private $syncronize;
    public function __construct(Syncronize $syncronize)
    {
        $this->syncronize = $syncronize;
    }
    /**
     * @Route("/",name="sync_index")
     */
    public function index(Request $request, Profiler $profiler)
    {  
        $message = "Hello";

        return $this->render( 'sync/output.html.twig', ['message' => $message ]); 

    }   
}
```

if I try to autowire the profiler in the constructor method then I get the error `public function __construct(Syncronize $syncronize, Profiler $profiler)`:

> Cannot autowire service "App\Controller\SyncController": argument
>   "$profiler" of method "__construct()" references class
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Profiler\Profiler" but no such service
>   exists. You should maybe alias this class to the existing "profiler"
>   service.

if I try to autowire the profiler in the index method then I get the error `public function index(Request $request, Profiler $profiler)`:

> Controller "App\Controller\SyncController::index()" requires that you
>   provide a value for the "$profiler" argument. Either the argument is
>   nullable and no null value has been provided, no default value has
>   been provided or because there is a non optional argument after this
>   one.

**EDIT**
For big queries disabling the profiler was not the solution... Actually you need to disable the setSQLLogger:

```
$em->getConnection()->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger(null);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Symfony 3.4 / 4**

https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/profiler/matchers.html

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Profiler\Profiler;

class DefaultController
{
    // ...

    public function someMethod(Profiler $profiler)
    {
        // for this particular controller action, the profiler is disabled
        $profiler->disable();

        // ...
    }
}
```

If you have an error with autowiring

```
# config/services.yaml
services:
    Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Profiler\Profiler: '@profiler'
```

---

**Old:**

If you want to disable the profiler from a controller, you can like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Profiler\Profiler;
// ...

class DefaultController
{
    // ...

    public function someMethod(Profiler $profiler)
    {
        // for this particular controller action, the profiler is disabled
        $profiler->disable();

        // ...
    }
}
```

Source: https://symfony.com/doc/current/profiler/matchers.html

Another way would be to use: `$this->get('profiler')->disable();`

---

**Older:**
Simply switch the app to `prod` mode and disable debug mode.

To do this, open the `.env` file on the server in your favourite editor (Note: You should never commit this file to Git, as you store secrets in there!).

In that file, you should see a section starting with: `###> symfony/framework-bundle ###`
Just below that there is a `APP_ENV=dev` and `APP_DEBUG=1`, change these two lines to `APP_ENV=prod` and `APP_DEBUG=0`. Then save the file.

Next you should clear the cache for prod mode and install the assets. To do this, run the following commands:

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
php bin/console cache:warmup --env=prod --no-debug
php bin/console assets:install --env=prod --no-debug --symlink
```

If you now load the application, it is in prod mode, which includes more caching and is faster as debug is disabled.

---

**Note:**
There will still be a timelimit for PHP. If you still hit that limit, you can either change your PHP setting or alternatively you could run the import from CLI, as CLI usually has no timelimit. If users need to be able to upload on their own, I'd suggest having them upload the file, enter a "note" about the file to a db and have a cronjob reading that db for not imported files and import them.

Comment: I just want to disable the the bundle in one action of the controller... in prod everything works ok

Comment: Does this help?

Comment: Thanks but I already tried that... my mistake for not adding that information in my question... i updated the question with code and errors

Comment: What if you use `$this->get('profiler')->disable();` instead?

Comment: Oh and with your example code on the updated question, you'll need to add `use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Profiler\Profiler;`

Comment: That line is on the code and I still get the error references class "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Profiler\Profiler" but no such service exists

Comment: I missed to add the alias on the services.yaml now it's working... thanks

Comment: You can't use the matcher anymore.
To make it work in SF4.4 you need to create a service alias as explained in the doc here  https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/profiler/matchers.html

Comment: Thanks @KaizokuGambare if you'd like you could do an edit of the answer and add it (or if it's fine with you I'll add it during the weekend)